# Finding connection between objects in a large list

Tags: python

I have a list of objects that are Network Devices so they have attributes such as name and methods such as connected_neighbors. I want to find all objects that are connected with each other to create link objects. I am doing something like below but it is turning out to be very slow

```
for ref_device in iter(devices):
    for device in iter(devices):
        if ref_dev.name in device.connected_neighbor_devices():
            print ref_dev.name + ' <--> ' + device.name
```

Update:
my data is basically a list of network device objects. These objects are generated from json which itself represents these network devices, their interfaces and neighbors on these interfaces. I have a very large list of network device objects each with several interfaces. I want to create link objects from this list where a link object will have two network device objects that are connected via any number of interfaces (or basically are neighbor of each other)

I have updated my code as follows

```
class Link(object):
    def __init__(self, dev_a, dev_b):
        self.dev_a = dev_a
        self.dev_b = dev_b
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(dev_a.name, dev_b.name)

links = []
names = {dev.name for dev in devices}
for ref_device in devices:
for neigh in ref_device.connected_neighbor_devices():
    if neigh in names:
        neigh_device = [d for d in devices if d.name == neigh][0]
        links.append(Link(ref_device, neigh_device))
```

Comment: Side-note: There is no reason to explicitly call `iter`. `for` loops implicitly call `iter` on the iterable they're passed, so you're just wasting time on (slow) explicit call when the (fast) implicit call has to occur no matter what.

Comment: We dont know your data and how the data is connected. But couldnt you remove already matched 'ref_device' from the list ? So, the loop 'for device in devices' is getting smaller as futher the loop runs.

Comment: my data is basically a list of network device objects. These objects are generated from json data which itself represents these network devices, their interfaces and neighbors on these interfaces. I have a very large list of network device objects each with several interfaces. I want to create link objects from this list where a link object will have two network device objects are connected via any number of interfaces (or basically are neighbor of each other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double-loop followed by membership test in results of `connected_neighbor_devices` seems unnecessary, since the method itself seems to get a sequence of connected device names. Surely you could do something like:

```
names = {dev.name for dev in devices}

for ref_device in devices:
    for connected_name in ref_device.connected_neighbor_devices():
        if connected_name in names:
            print ref_device.name + ' <--> ' + connected_name
```

The creation of that initial `set` and the test for membership is just to ensure that connected devices not part of your `devices` collections are not included in the output. This might not match the ordering of your existing code, but that can be changed if needed; assuming `connected_neighbor_devices` returns all the names of connected devices, this should get what you want, but with `O(n)` calls to and scans of the results from `connected_neighbor_devices`, not `O(n ** 2)`.

Comment: I think even ```if connected_name in names:``` isn't needed.

Comment: @wwii: If `devices` covers all possible connected devices, no, it isn't needed. If `devices` might be a subset of all possible devices, and you don't want output for other devices, you'd need the test.

Comment: see my updated code. this is working faster but I have duplicate links now. Will try to fix this

Comment: Your new code is adding an extra round of searching to map from device name back to device. Perhaps make a `dict` mapping names to device objects, so you can perform that mapping as `O(1)` lookup instead of `O(n)` linear scan? Admittedly, unless `devices` is pretty large, this probably wouldn't be a big cost.

Comment: ok will investigate, how can I remove duplicity here. If a link is created I dont want to create it again. So dev_a <-> dev_b is equal to dev_b <-> dev_a and I dont want it to appear twice in links

Comment: @zsh: Well, obvious solution is, since names are unique and are strings, store them in alphabetical order. That is, when you create a link, store the lower value as `dev_a` and the higher value as `dev_b`. Then define a `__eq__` and `__hash__` for your class, so it can be stored in a `set` which will uniquify for you. Alternatively, you just don't store any link that would require reversal, since you'll generate them in both directions anyway, you can skip storing any link where it would map to an alphabetically earlier name.

Comment: If you have some better way to determine connectivity for any given pair of devices without calling the "get _all_ connected devices" method (which I assume is expensive), you could just loop over `for dev_a, dev_b in itertools.combinations(sorted(devices, key=lambda dev: dev.name), 2):` and store whenever `is_connected(dev_a, dev_b)`, `combinations` combined with `sorted` up front gets you the same ordering (all `dev_a` less than paired `dev_b`) and uniqueness guarantees.